# Lookup key inside array of object in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app I need the functionality to look up contact info data to check if a user already exists in my database. As it's possible that a user has multiple email addresses I'm storing this data in a separate class called `ContactInfo`.

Now I want to query all objects and check if an email is contained in the 
`emails` array inside `ContactInfo`. Therefore I'm using the email as key, that's why it's URL encoded. However I can't figure out the right query to achieve this.

---

**contactInfo**

- -KYd3pbZ7D--yX6B3HY8

  - emails

    - john%40gmail%2Ecom: true
    - john%40hotmail%2Ecom: true
  - firstname: John
  - lastname: Doe
- -KYdUDoMVOdUmJ4I3jO-

  - emails

    - jane%40gmail%2Ecom: true
  - firstname: Jane
  - lastname: Doe

Based on that the top level of my database looks like this

[image]

Comment: Two quick things: 1) Please don't post images of structures in questions - post the actual text version as then we can copy/paste into our answer and it's also searchable.  2) Your question says 'array' and you don't actually have a Firebase array in your structure. This is a good thing (please don't use arrays), but you should probably update the question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an email address as a key is probably not what you want to do.

email addresses change and are considered dynamic data - it's best practice not use dynamic data (something that may change) as a key as if it does change, everywhere it's referenced in your database would also have to be updated.

One possibility is to store multiple emails as such:

```
contactInfo
    -KYd3pbZ7D--yX6B3HY8
         firstname: "John"
         lastname: "Doe"
         main_email: "-JYJkjajisaiisd"
```

and then a separate node for all of the emails.

```
contact_emails
    -JYJkjajisaiisd
       email : "john@gmail.com"
       uid : "uid_0"
    -YJNlkokaosomdo
       email : "john@hotmail.com",
       uid : "uid_0"
    -Juiaisidiasda
       email : "frank@fmail.com",
       uid : "uid_3"
```

This structure is query-able, maintainable and avoids having to worry about parsing/storing special characters (email chars) as a key. You can store multiple emails per person and you can change their main email by just updating the main_email node within their contactInfo

To check for emails, use this query

```
    contactEmailsRef.queryOrdered(byChild:"email")
          .queryEqual(toValue: "john@hotmail.com")
          .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

                print(snapshot)

    })
```

will result in this node being printed

```
-YJNlkokaosomdo
     email : "john@hotmail.com",
     uid : "uid_0"
```

Comment: Many thanks for your nice answer. I totally understand your point about using email as a key. However I'm still not sure how the query would look like to check if, e.g. "john@gmail.com" exists in the system (i.e. going through all `contactInfo` objects)

Comment: @user1463853 Great comment! I goofed in my original answer, so it's been updated to correctly answer you question. In this case, if there is a valid snapshot in the closure, then the email was found and already exists. If snapshot is null then it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. :)