# Unwrap String? Into String - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase

I am updating information to Firebase Database with a User Default variable.

I have tried YouTubing this, and nothing worked. Stopped at library, nothing shows.

```
let email = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "EMAIL") as? String
self.databaseRefer.child(email).childByAutoId().setValue("Visal")
```

The Output is always the SIBGART error on the iOS Debug Statement

I expect the output to be normal, and update info to firebase

Comment: Please avoid using email addresses as node keys. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41085158/lookup-key-inside-array-of-object-in-firebase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
guard let email = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "EMAIL") else {
   return
}

self.databaseRefer.child(email).childByAutoId().setValue("Visal")
```

Comment: That Works! Thanks So Much!

Comment: @user11234693 While this is a correct answer, there may be an underlying issue which is not addressed: email address make poor node keys. Email addresses change and if they do, you will have to read in, delete, and re-write every single reference to that node in Firebase. Additionally, emails contain characters that are not valid in Firebase node keys.